# Selective data transfer

Tags: verilog

How do I transfer particular bits of data from input to output?

```
module (a ,b, ...);
   input  [31:0] a;
   output [15:0] b;
endmodule
```

How I can transfer only the first sixteen bits of `input a` to `output b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a part-select:

```
assign b = a[15:0];
```